# Place text in R plot where there is empty space

Tags: r, plot

I need to add some text to several different plots in R. The best location for this text will depend on where each particular plot has no(t many) points, to minimize text/point overlap. Example:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(cars)
text(5, 100, "some text here.", adj = 0, cex = 0.7)
plot(iris[ , 3:4])
text(3, 0.5, "some text here.", adj = 0, cex = 0.7)
```

[image]

Is there a way (preferably with base R) to automatically get a good placement for the text in each plot, instead of me having to first look at each plot and then set `5, 100` and `3, 0.5` manually?

Comment: Not base graphics, but the `ggrepel` package (works with `ggplot2`) has some ability to work around data points. It's stochastic and, while good, does not always succeed in this endeavor.

Comment: Not really automatic but more convenient, try `legend("topleft", legend="some text here.", cex = 0.7)`; `legend("bottomright", legend="some text here.", cex = 0.7)`. See _Details_ in `?legend` for more options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of any built-in function, but it is not hard to write a function to compute the emptiest quadrant. The comment by @jay.sf mentioned "topright" etc. Those keywords work for `legend` but do not seem to work in `text`  so I will use `legend` to write the text. First, the function

```
emptyQuadrant = function(x) {
    mid1 = sum(range(x[,1]))/2
    mid2 = sum(range(x[,2]))/2
    Q1 = sum(x[,1]>=mid1 & x[,2]>=mid2)
    Q2 = sum(x[,1]<=mid1 & x[,2]>=mid2)
    Q3 = sum(x[,1]<=mid1 & x[,2]<=mid2)
    Q4 = sum(x[,1]>=mid1 & x[,2]<=mid2)
    BestQ = which.min(c(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4))
    return(c("topright", "topleft", 
        "bottomleft", "bottomright")[BestQ])
}
```

Now you can just compute the best location for the legend.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(iris[ , 1:2])
legend(emptyQuadrant(iris[,1:2]), "some text here.", cex = 0.7, bty='n')
plot(iris[ , 3:4])
legend(emptyQuadrant(iris[,3:4]), "some text here.", cex = 0.7, bty='n')
```

[image: Plots with carefully placed text]